# How to store object by keys values with arrays

Tags: javascript

I have object and values are arrays. I want to store and print this obj by biger sum in arrays.

```
let obj = {
  Teri: [2,4,2,6],
  Misho: [5,6,4,5],
  Boby: [3,5,6],
  Adi: [6,6,4,8]
};
```

Comment: Please read through the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help), in particular [How do I ask a good question?](/help/how-to-ask) Your best bet here is to do your research, [search](/help/searching) for related topics on SO, and give it a go. If you get stuck and can't get unstuck after doing more research and searching, post a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of your attempt and say specifically where you're stuck. People will be glad to help.

Comment: what is the desired output? Please add it in the question

Comment: ` I want to store and print this obj by biger sum in arrays.`this is not clear pls explain

Comment: Sorry, I could not find anything similar.

Comment: Teri have 2+4+2+6 = 14;  Misho have 5+6+4+5 = 20 and i just want to console.log(New array)  ex: 1.is Bigger 2. next one and so on

Comment: You will not find a similar answer always, you will just need to break down your questions and search for one piece at a time.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```js
let obj = {Teri: [2,4,2,6], Misho: [5,6,4,5], Boby: [3,5,6], Adi: [6,6,4,8]}
           
const sum = arr => arr.reduce((a, b)=> a+b ,0)
const r = Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(obj).sort((a,b)=> sum(b[1]) - sum(a[1])))

console.log(r)
```

with AVG function

```js
  let obj = {Teri: [2,4,2,6], Misho: [5,6,4,5], Boby: [3,5,6], Adi: [6,6,4,8]}
               
  const avg = arr => arr.reduce((a, b)=> a+b ,0)/arr.length
  const r = Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(obj).sort((a,b)=> avg(b[1]) - avg(a[1])))
console.log(r)
```

Descending by the second value

```js
  let obj = {Teri: [50, 100], Misho: [40, 80], Boby: [30,165], Adi: [80, 120]}
               
  const r = Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(obj).sort((a,b)=> b[1][1] - a[1][1]))
console.log(r)
```

Comment: Аnd now another question? I'm trying to sort them by average.... :)

Comment: @SvetoslavIvanov try now :)

Comment: Guessed :) Many Thanks!

Comment: @SvetoslavIvanov you are welcome :)

Comment: let obj = {Teri: [50, 100], Misho: [40, 80], Boby: [30,165], Adi: [80, 120]} I'm wondering, if I want to sort them (descending) by the second value in array?

Comment: @SvetoslavIvanov, yes you can,  i updated my post, try now :)